# Magento changing mini cart checkout behaviour

Tags: magento

I'm trying to change the behavior of my mini cart checkout button to take people to a different URL then what we currently have.

I can see the code i need to change in chrome's inspector but i can't for the life of my find the file to edit on our server.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the line you want to change and use find tool of your IDE to find this line of code.

Comment: The trouble i'm having is finding the actual file the code is located in.